# How to fetch random values of textarea on button click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, textarea

I'm developing a tying speed test tool. I need to add a functionality where I can fetch random paragraphs from MYSQL DB on clicking a "next" button.
How can I achieve this? Can anyone please help?
Here is my code for index.php:

```
 <div class="float-left col-3  mt-5">
              <button type="button" id="timer" class="btn timer-disp">0:00</button>
              <button type="button" id="reset" class="btn btn-info">Retry</button>
              <button type="button" id="change" class="btn btn-secondary">Next</button>
              <div id="new-text">

              </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-12 mt-5">                   
                <button type="button" id="readCookie" class="btn btn-secondary d-none">Read Cookie</button>
            </div>
            <div>
            <textarea name="" id="input_text" cols="30" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam varius at felis quis imperdiet. In sagittis nisi mauris, convallis faucibus metus porttitor vel. Nullam posuere ac augue a cursus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer sollicitudin dui non nisi posuere mattis at quis erat. Aenean odio purus, dictum sed lacinia non, tincidunt nec magna. Integer in aliquet felis, rutrum rhoncus magna. Nulla nec augue eu nisl pretium laoreet. In sapien turpis, vestibulum at urna sed, accumsan imperdiet nibh. Morbi in lectus nunc. Aliquam imperdiet felis mi, vel convallis metus finibus vitae. Nunc dictum, nulla vitae maximus ultrices, libero mi aliquet ipsum, et mattis nunc arcu non turpis.

              Quisque mollis nunc vitae dignissim porttitor. In vitae iaculis quam. Fusce posuere neque eget quam faucibus, sed semper turpis tincidunt. Aenean a fermentum dui, sit amet convallis tellus. Aenean luctus turpis elit, commodo euismod quam placerat vitae. Aenean id rhoncus felis, non tempor sapien. Suspendisse mauris magna, luctus sit amet egestas vel, hendrerit non est. Nulla eget elit </textarea>
            </div>
```

This is add-text.php:

```
<?php 

$host         = "localhost";

$username     = "root";

$password     = "";

$dbname       = "add-text";

$result_array = array();
/* Create connection */
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

/* Check connection  */
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection to database failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
/* SQL query to get results from database */

$sql = "SELECT  string FROM text ORDER BY RAND ( ) LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
/* If there are results from database push to result array */

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($result_array, $row);
    }
}
/* send a JSON encded array to client */
echo json_encode($result_array);

$conn->close();
```

and it is the script I'm using:

```
$("#change").on('click', function(){ 

$.ajax({ 

  method: "GET", 

  url: "add-text.php",

}).done(function( data ) { 

  var result= $.parseJSON(data); 

  var string='';

 /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */

  $.each( result, function( key, value ) { 

    string += "<tr> <td>"+'   \
              <td>'+value['string']+"</td> </tr>"; 
        }); 

       string += '</table>'; 

    $("#new-text").html(string); 
 }); 
});
```

This code successfully fetches the data but does not display it on the textarea and does not allow multiple clicks.

Comment: `/* from result create a string of data and append to the div */` it will append to the div, not textarea. Also, `$("#new-text").html(string); ` is inside the loop, which means it will override the data every loop.

Comment: couldn't understand. can you please explain it through code @FelippeDuarte